# Problems with OnebyOne slider on Iphone. - I have tried the "cursor: pointer;" workaround without any success

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

First of all, I am not a coder/developer more like a designer/animator. 
Thats is probably why things dont work out as expected on Iphone/ipad. 
I have this website - foxlord.com and everything works ok on desktop browsers but on Iphone/Ipad. 
The two large buttons ("watch demo video & download now") will not function.
I know that the code is super messy, but I have tried to use the cursor: pointer; workaround without any success.
I have read a lot of posts on this forum and on other ones as well, but I cant seem to make it work.
Any ideas?
I dont know if this is ok, but if somebody will take a look and make it work on iphone/Ipad as well I am willing to pay. I can send you the files you need to test.
Frustrated regards from Norway.

```
.download_btn {
cursor:pointer;
width:98px;
height:42px;
display:block;
position:relative;
left:150px;
top:-52px;
margin-top:0px;
padding:10px 0 0 69px;
font-size:14px;
color:#f8f9f1;
/*text-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #a4633a;*/  
font-family: 'HelveticaLTStdRoman';
background:url(../images/download_btn.png) no-repeat;
line-height:18px;
z-index:500;
background-position:0 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you are having trouble with in the question.

Comment: Again, *in the question*.

Comment: Use the edit button on the question itself to add it. Don't put code in the comments.

Comment: This is the css that controlls the button.

Comment: Also when I test the site on desktop safari with ios7 iphone option on. Everything works ok, but not when i test it on the actual iphone